# is there any possibility in terraform to enable Encryption in transit

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform

I'm trying to enable Encryption in transit for my environment variable in lambda.
However I couldn't find any possible documentation in terraform to fix this?

I was able to create and attach customer master key in lambda. `kms_key_arn`

I have created this :

```
data "aws_kms_ciphertext" "secret_encryption" {
  key_id    = aws_kms_key.kms_key.key_id
  plaintext = <<EOF
  {
    "token": "${var.token}"
  }
EOF
}
```

now in my lambda's environment variable :

```
environment {
    variables = {
      ENV_TOKEN      = data.aws_kms_ciphertext.secret_encryption.ciphertext_blob
}
```

also I attached the kms:decryt to lambda execution role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "kms:Decrypt",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:XXXX:XXXX:key/1234-567-...."
    }
}
```

In my lambda:

```
encrypted_token = os.environ["ENV_TOKEN"]
    decrypt_github_token = boto3.client('kms').decrypt(                                       CiphertextBlob=base64.b64decode(encrypted_token)
                                   )['Plaintext'].decode('utf-8')
```

But i'm getting "An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the Decrypt operation:when calling the Decrypt operation: The ciphertext refers to a customer master key that does not exist, does not exist in this region, or you are not allowed to access."

does anyone knows where i'm doing wrong.
Should the encryption be only `value` format not the `key value` format?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-encryption - you simply need to manually encrypt the environment variables when storing them and then add code for decrypting them within the lambda code. Afaik the lambda service itself does not offer any dedicated transit encryption support, the frontend is just helpful in encrypting the variables but from the lambda service perspective the variables are regular variables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is happening prior to decryption. I wonder if you can't even read the key itself. You can test this by appending "kms:DescribeKey".

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:DescribeKey"
           ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:XXXX:XXXX:key/1234-567-...."
    }
}
```